# Can I save and reload in Zerg Hunter RPG: Betrayal for StarCraft II?

Tags: starcraft-2, mods

This question refers to the custom map **[Zerg Hunter RPG](http://www.zhrpg.net/): Betrayal** version 0.98 for StarCraft II.

I am attempting to save the game and reload it later. The menu, where I would normally go to save regular games of StarCraft II, appear to have saving disabled. There is a big "Save" button onscreen at all times, but clicking it says "Loading this character later will reset you to level 1," which makes me wonder why it's even there all the time.  Occasionally, the game would appear to autosave, but I'm not sure how to actually load it back up later.

The full map took my friends and I about 2 hours to beat. We would like to play it again with different heroes, but would much rather if we could break it down into smaller chunks rather than having to do the whole thing in 1 go.

Is there any way to save our progress through Betrayal and start it back up again later?

**Edit**: Just played a bit to find more info. It looks like saving your character allows you to reload the character's *items* but not levels or progress. I am looking for a way to save progress so I don't need to do the whole map in 1 sitting.

Answer (score 1):

Features for custom maps in Starcraft 2 are at the mercy of the developer. The editor is so immensely powerful that a map developer has many different ways at their disposal to provide saving features it really can be a bit overwhelming. Furthermore not every map developer offers such a feature, or even knows how to implement it.

As such the saving feature you're more familiar with (I'm assuming the campaign saving feature) is not the same when it comes to Custom Maps. It's best to contact the developer to request such a feature.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, there's only one way available to save stuff - the bank.